Выбор стека для OLAP системы
У меня есть задача по учебе в универе, необходимо разработать/организовать OLAP систему для аналитики. Проблема в том что преподы застряли в году так в 2010, предлагают использовать mondrian, который работает не выше java8. Я его развернул, но он очень старый. В принципе само хранилище готово(точнее её модель) организованно оно по пока по самому простому варианту - звезда Кимбалла. Но встал вопрос где эти собранные данные обрабатывать. Есть такие решения как Redash? Apache Superset, MetaBase. Все они отлично строят дашборды и рисуют графики. Но мне требуется ещё и такие возможности как отображение таблиц с такими возможностями OLAP систем как вращение, проекция, раскрытие(drill-down) и свертка(roll-up/drill-up), сечение(slice-and-dice). Есть варианты с Pentaho bi-service + saiku. Но они тоже сильно устарели(последний коммит 8лет назад) хотя и по моложе мондриана.
